# New class containing factor does not inherit method for factor in new version of R (3.3.1)

Tags: r, oop, inheritance, r-s4

On the new R version (3.3.1) when making a new class that contains a `factor` as the `S3` part of the class it looks like the new class does not inherit behavior expected from a class that is based on a `factor` type.

```
> setClass('newFactor', representation = c(tempValue='character'), contains = 'factor')
> ttt<-new('newFactor',tempValue='ddd')
> S3Part(ttt)<-factor(c('a','b','c'))
> table(S3Part(ttt))

a b c 
1 1 1 
> table(ttt)
Error in as.character.factor(x) : attempting to coerce non-factor
>
```

This worked fine on a older R version I tried:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works again in R-devel:

```
> setClass('newFactor', contains = 'factor')
> ttt<-new('newFactor', factor(c('a','b','c')))
> table(ttt)
ttt
a b c 
1 1 1 
> R.version.string
[1] "R Under development (unstable) (2016-08-30 r71172)"
```

The correct place to report this is the R-devel [mailing list](https://stat.ethz.ch/mailman/listinfo/r-devel) or bug tracker.

Comment: Yes, I thought it was a bug but wanted to make sure before i file it as one thank you